# Electronics components casing or packaging style types and diferences?

Tags: components, packages

Is there any good **visual** guide or reference that explains the different types of casing styles like these ones that I come across every time I try to buy a component on [farnell](http://uk.farnell.com) website:

```
017AA, 0201, 0402, 1005, 403A, 403C, Axial Leaded, DFN, DO-15, DO-201, 
DO-201AE, DO-202AA, DO-204AC, DO-204AL, DO-214, DO-214AA, DO-214AB, 
DO-214AC, DO-215AA, DO-216AA, DO-218AB, DO-221AC, DO-222AA, DO-41, 
Flip Chip, FlipChip, MicroSMP, MLP, MSOP, NSOIC, P600, R6, SC-70, 
SC-74, SC-75, SC-88, SLP1006P2, SLP1616P6, SLP2510P8, SLP2626P10, 
SMD, SOD-123, SOD-123FL, SOD-123W, SOD-128, SOD-323, SOD-523, SOD-923, 
SOD-963, SOIC, SOT-143, SOT-23, SOT-323, SOT-363, SOT-523, SOT-553, 
SOT-563, SOT-666, SOT-723, SOT-953, TO-263, TO-277A, TSLP-2-19, 
TSLP-2-20, TSOP, TSSLP-2-3, TSSLP-2-4, TSSOP, UDFN, UQFN, WLCSP, WLL-2-1
```

Often I buy through hole components and I would want to know which of above casings fit my needs but I have no clue (Except from the "Axial leaded" one which is obvious), but also I want to learn about the other types.

Comment: who said any others were THT?

Comment: I don't know any of the other packaging styles so I assumed some of them might be THT (if by that you mean through hole).

Comment: If you search for anything at Digikey site and choose "bulk" ( and in stock) then it ought to filter out tape and reel parts, so you see which packages remain.

Comment: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/c/7/a/1/9/51e0633cce395f867b000000.jpg

Comment: Firstly do you only need this for the diode section? Secondly couldn't you, albeit tediously, use the search tool and in the package type section, select one package by one and based on the results you can determine what kind of package it is?

Comment: I think almost everything you list is surface-mount (or worse :-) ), except axial leaded.  Radial lead will also have wire leads.  DIP and SIP, and some TO-nnn packages are also non-surface-mount.  To be sure, you have to study the datasheets for parts you are interested in.

Comment: @Bradman175 No not just diodes (I was looking for TVs when I posted this question) but in general. When I read a case style like SO-xxx or TO-xxx I want to know how does it look like intuitevly, there are so many types of them and examining them one by one takes a long time, I was hoping that they were documented somewhere.

Comment: @user7342539 so essentially you want us to provide a list of through hole components along with specifics as well? I don't have a list of through hole packages for TVS but I have it for BJTs and MOSFETs, specifically for the farnell website because I use it as well.

Comment: @Bradman175 At the moment I'm mainly interested in THT but I would be interested in SMD in the near future. I'm not sure how extensive the list would be for all components or if each style is specific for one component or not but something like the image posted in the comments above by Tony Stewart is very helpful, it would be great if the acronyms are also explained like (DIP = dual in package) so that it would be easier to remember but not essential.